# I don't want Angular Material to add a md-button when I use ng-click on md-list-item

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I need something like this:

```
<md-list-item ng-click="something()"> ... </md-list-item>
```

But Angular Material compiles it to:

```
<md-list-item role="listitem" tabindex="-1" class="ng-scope md-clickable">
  <button class="md-no-style md-button" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="something()">
    ...
  </button>
</md-list-item>
```

What? You may think it's clever, but it is not even documented! In my case it looks ugly and works rather badly, and it's not even valid HTML (creates buttons inside buttons). If I wanted an AM button with all styles etc. I would use a button, but here I want only a simple working ng-click on a md-list-item. If it's necessary to have different element then please create a `<div>` inside but not a button? Can I somehow prevent Angular Material from compiling it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oops, looks like nope.

below is the source code of that behavior

```
if (tAttrs.ngClick || tAttrs.ngHref || tAttrs.href || tAttrs.uiSref || tAttrs.ngAttrUiSref) {
    wrapIn('button');
}
```

if you create your own ng-click, then you might be able to bypass this logic.

Comment: Eh. Thank you for finding this. It's really bad it was designed this way, it should have been possible to turn it off like with md-no-ink. I'll create an issue on Github.

Comment: Any feedback on this? I am having similar issues trying to generate a plain md-list with no listeners or inks. Sadly I'm going to go opt for custom elements for this and not material way